# No tests found for given includes: JUNIT

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, junit, mockito

I wrote a test for my method from the service, but the test won't run. Gives an error message! I did everything strictly according to the guide, I did not add anything new. There are few solutions to this problem on the Internet. What could be the problem?

P.S. I tried changing in runner `settings` -> `test runner` -> `Gradle` / `Intelij Idea` - not works.

```java
Testing started at 17:43 ...

> Task :compileJava UP-TO-DATE
> Task :processResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :classes UP-TO-DATE
> Task :compileTestJava
> Task :processTestResources NO-SOURCE
> Task :testClasses
> Task :test FAILED
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':test'.
> No tests found for given includes: [ru.coffeetearea.service.OrderServiceTest.setOrderService](filter.includeTestsMatching)
* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
BUILD FAILED in 1s
4 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 2 up-to-date
```

build.gradle:

```java
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

// Без этих опций Mapstruct выдает ошибку на кириллицу!
compileJava.options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
compileTestJava.options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
//

dependencies {
    // Thymeleaf
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf', version: '2.3.3.RELEASE'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-validation
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-validation', version: '2.3.3.RELEASE'
    // Swagger UI
    compile group: 'io.springfox', name: 'springfox-swagger-ui', version: '2.9.2'
    // Swagger 2
    compile group: 'io.springfox', name: 'springfox-swagger2', version: '2.9.2'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot', version: '2.3.1.RELEASE'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-data-jpa', version: '2.3.1.RELEASE'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-jdbc
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-jdbc', version: '2.3.1.RELEASE'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.postgresql/postgresql
    compile group: 'org.postgresql', name: 'postgresql', version: '42.2.14'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-web
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-web', version: '2.3.1.RELEASE'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-data-jpa', version: '2.3.1.RELEASE'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.flywaydb/flyway-core
    compile group: 'org.flywaydb', name: 'flyway-core', version: '6.5.1'
    // MapStruct
    implementation 'org.mapstruct:mapstruct:1.3.1.Final'
    annotationProcessor 'org.mapstruct:mapstruct-processor:1.3.1.Final'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.projectlombok/lombok
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.12'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.12'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate.orm/hibernate-jpamodelgen
    annotationProcessor('org.hibernate:hibernate-jpamodelgen:6.0.0.Alpha5')
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-security
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-security', version: '2.3.2.RELEASE'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.jsonwebtoken/jjwt
    compile group: 'io.jsonwebtoken', name: 'jjwt', version: '0.9.1'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.xml.bind/jaxb-api
    compile group: 'javax.xml.bind', name: 'jaxb-api', version: '2.4.0-b180830.0359'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mockito/mockito-junit-jupiter
    testCompile group: 'org.mockito', name: 'mockito-junit-jupiter', version: '3.5.10'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-test
    testCompile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-test', version: '2.3.3.RELEASE'

    testImplementation('org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.4.0')

    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
    }
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

method makeOrder():

```java
public OrderDTO makeOrder(MakeOrderDTO makeOrderDTO) {

        Long userId = JwtUser.getCurrentUserID();

        Order order = orderRepository.findByUserIdAndOrderStatus(userId, OrderStatus.NEW);

        if (order == null) {
            throw new MainNullPointerException("Ошибка! Ваша корзина пуста!");
        }
        order.setTotalCost(calculateOrderPrice(order));
        order.setAddress(makeOrderDTO.getAddress());
        order.setPhoneNumber(makeOrderDTO.getPhoneNumber());
        order.setDateOrder(new Date());
        order.setOrderStatus(OrderStatus.ACTIVE);

        orderRepository.save(order);

        return orderMapper.orderToOrderDTO(order);
    }
```

My tests for method:

```java
package ru.coffeetearea.service;

import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockBean;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;
import ru.coffeetearea.dto.MakeOrderDTO;
import ru.coffeetearea.dto.OrderDTO;
import ru.coffeetearea.mappers.OrderMapper;
import ru.coffeetearea.model.Order;
import ru.coffeetearea.repository.OrderRepository;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
class OrderServiceTest {

    @MockBean
    private OrderRepository orderRepository;

    @MockBean
    private OrderMapper orderMapper;

    private OrderService orderService;


    @Autowired
    public void setOrderService(OrderService orderService) {
        this.orderService = orderService;
    }


    @Test
    void makeOrder() {

        MakeOrderDTO makeOrderDTO = new MakeOrderDTO();

        OrderDTO orderDTO = orderService.makeOrder(makeOrderDTO);

        Assert.assertNotNull(orderDTO.getAddress());
        Assert.assertNotNull(orderDTO.getPhoneNumber());
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it may be related to your folder hierarchy.

Try to make your test folder hierarchy exactly the same as you src folder. Example:

[image]

Make sure you have set up your project structure the right sources. See the picture of intellij setup for project structure (right click on project > open module settings > modules > sources)

[image]

Comment: I add my structure in question

Comment: Please open up main folder as well

Comment: Try maybe create one more `@SpringBootApplication` with a method with no body on `test/java` folder. And this is my last guess